# Trying to build Cyanogenmod 7 - can't find wifi.h

Tags: android, build, cyanogenmod

I try to build Cyanogenmod 7 (Android 2.3.7) for my ZTE Tureis.

The build stops at

```
frameworks/base/core/jni/android_net_wifi_Wifi.cpp:26:18: error: wifi.h: No such file or directory
```

When I open up the cpp file and change

```
<include "wifi.h">
```

to

```
<#include "../../../hardware/libhardware_legacy/include/hardware_legacy/wifi.h">
```

the build passes this one but it complains later on about missing headers in other files again.

Any ideas here? I already made a new repo sync, all files should be in place.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this line in Android.mk file where you are trying to include `"wifi.h"`

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(call include-path-for, libhardware_legacy)/hardware_legacy
```